# asp.net keeps on calling a function in page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've a form (mainpage.aspx), on which there's a button called 'Cancel'. Here's the  code for the button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
```

and the called function

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("EventList.aspx");
    }
```

So as you can see, what the button do is simple. Just go to another page. But it seems here that doesn't happen. Every time I click the Cancel button, first it will try to load the code

```
Response.Redirect("EventList.aspx");
```

but then somehow it will try to execute the codes below:

```
if (hdnEventId.Value != "" && hdnEventId.Value != "0")
            {
                LoadEvent();
}
```

I know this because I put a breakpoint on Response.Redirect("EventList.aspx"); and after that I step into the code above

btw the codes above are located inside

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

inside the file mainpage.aspx.cs

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Page_Load` is called on **any** postback and you're actually doing a postback by clicking Cancel. The solution is to wrap your non-postback specific code in a `IsPostBack` check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (hdnEventId.Value != "" && hdnEventId.Value != "0")
        {
            LoadEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @M_Griffiths Haha always the case, if I had 10 rep for everytime I'd abandoned an answer because someone beat me to it I'd have more rep than Jon Skeet :)

Comment: @mattytommo but the codes that're being called are already inside if (!Page.IsPostBack)

Comment: @mattytommo I already did what you asked but the problem still happens. It still try to load the LoadEvent()

Comment: @imin So when you put a breakpoint in `Page_Load`, it actually hits when you've redirected? And `IsPostback` is false?

Comment: @mattytommo yes, Page_Load is being hit again. And Yes, IsPostBack is false. Just in case, I'm using the URL rewriting module, if that helps.

Comment: @imin So it looks like you're getting redirected back to your main page somehow. There's no redirect set up in your `EventInfo` page is it? What are you URL rewriting in this instance? Is the main page your fallback page for URLs that the rewriter can't match?

Comment: Err.. .sorry I can't fully grasp what u're asking. Anyway yes, the page EventList.aspx is the fallback page for URLs that the rewriter can't match